# Laravel Stateless api jwt-auth and csrf token

Tags: reactjs, laravel, jwt

we are building website using `laravel` and `react`. also this two applications separated, `laravel` side only `api` and working on

```
api.example.com
```

and one `react` application working on 
`example.com`

For authentication, we are using `JWT` and holding token secure httpOnly cookie. Our problem is also we want to use CSRF token but I'm getting `The payload is invalid.`

error, that's what I do

```
App\Http\Kernel.php
     /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            'throttle:60,1',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

```
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php

     /**
     * Get a JWT via given credentials.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login()
    {
        $credentials = request(['username', 'password']);

        if (!isset($credentials['username']) || !isset($credentials['password'])) {
            return response()->json('You need to fill username and password.', 401);
        }
        $user = User::where('username', '=', $credentials['username'])->first();

        if (!($user && Hash::check($credentials['password'], $user->password))) {
            return response()->json('invalid_credentials', 401);
        }
        $token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
        $payload = JWTAuth::setToken($token)->getPayload();
        $cookie = Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('token', $token, config('jwt.ttl'), '/', null, true, true));
        return response()->json($user, 200);
    }
```

When i'm testing with Postman i can get

```
laravel_session, XSRF-TOKEN, token
```

cookies and login working without problem, on postman i'm getting cookie

```
pm.environment.set("xsrf-token", decodeURIComponent(pm.cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN")))
```

with that code and adding headers to

```
X-XSRF-TOKEN: {{xsrf-token}}
```

with that code. When i'm doing post i'm getting

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException: The payload is invalid. in file /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php on line 195
```

how we can fix that problem? Thank you very much for helping.

Full Error:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\DecryptException: The payload is invalid. in file /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php on line 195

#0 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php(136): Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter->getJsonPayload()
#1 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(154): Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter->decrypt()
#2 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(136): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->getTokenFromRequest()
#3 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(74): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->tokensMatch()
#4 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle()
#5 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(56): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#6 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle()
#7 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#8 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle()
#9 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#10 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle()
#11 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#12 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(683): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then()
#13 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(658): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
#14 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(624): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute()
#15 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(613): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute()
#16 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(170): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch()
#17 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}()
#18 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/fruitcake/laravel-cors/src/HandleCors.php(31): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#19 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors->handle()
#20 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#21 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle()
#22 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#23 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle()
#24 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#25 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle()
#26 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(63): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#27 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle()
#28 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#29 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(171): Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies->handle()
#30 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#31 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(145): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then()
#32 /home/vagrant/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
#33 /home/vagrant/project/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle()
#34 {main}
```

Comment: Try it without the `decodeURIComponent` function.

Comment: When i do that, i'm getting Page Expired error.

Comment: So that tells you the csrf token is working fine. It is something else that is the issue.

Comment: Then, what did i wrong? I'm getting csrf_token with cookies, and sending back. How can i fix that problem?

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: I updated post, thats with ```decodeURIComponent```  error, without it i'm getting only 419 Page Expired.

Comment: Well, without it gets you past the `decode()`, so it seems that without it you get a valid payload. Seems like you may need to start digging into the source code in your vendor directory and do some `dd()` debugging to figure out what's going wrong.